# Using subprocess to run multiple commands depending on the list for ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to use subprocess to send some commands to ffmpeg. But I need to send different commands depending on how many items are in my list.

```
subs = ['https://example1.vtt', 'https://example2.vtt']
link = 'https://example.m3u8'
```

I tried doing this :

```
sub_list = []
for sub in subs:
    subtitles = "'-i' " + sub + " "
    sub_list.append(subtitles)
    result_subs = "".join(sub_list)
```

this makes the result_subs to be

```
'-i' example1.vtt '-i' example2.vtt
```

then I run :

```
subprocess.run([ffmpeg, '-i', link, result_subs, '-vcodec', 'copy', '-acodec', 'copy',  "test.mkv"])
```

but it gives me an error

Comment: You should be appending a _list_, not a string.

Comment: And the quotes in `"'-i' ..."` are wrong. Those quotes in a shell command are instructions **to the shell itself**, they never reach ffmpeg; just like the quotes in the Python string `'-i'` are Python syntax, and `-i` is the content that goes to ffmpeg as an argument _after the quotes are removed_.

Comment: The original command is like running `ffmpeg -i 'https://example.m3u8' "'-i' https://example1.vtt '-i' https://example2.vtt" -vcodec copy -acodec copy test.mkv` at a shell -- if you try it, you'll see that fails the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Each `-i`, and each input file name, should be a separate entry in your argument vector (the input list for `subprocess.run()`).

```
sub_list = []
for sub in subs:
    sub_list.append('-i')
    sub_list.append(sub)

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', link] \
               + sub_list \
               + ['-vcodec', 'copy', '-acodec', 'copy', "test.mkv"])
```

Comment: @CognizantApe, the OP is passing in the executable path for ffmpeg via a variable in their original code. Leaving it unquoted is thus intentional.

Comment: I see. I just think this is a better answer if it reduces dependence on code that is not shown in the question or answer.